Is this geometry question incorrect?

$X$ is any point on $AB$, and the median $AD$ of triangle
$\triangle{ABC}$ meets $XC$ at $Y$.
Prove that $\frac{XY}{YC} = \frac{AX}{XB}$.

Solution Attempt:

Extend $BY$ to $Z$. Cevians $AD$, $CX$ and $BZ$ concur at $Y$. Hence, by Ceva's Theorem:
$$ \frac{AX}{XB} \cdot  \frac{BD}{DC} \cdot  \frac{CZ}{AZ} = 1$$
Since $AD$ is a median, $ \frac{BD}{DC} = 1$, and thus:
$$ \frac{AX}{XB} =  \frac{AZ}{ZC} $$ Note that I am not using directed segments.
Thus, by Thale's Theorem, $XZ \parallel BC$. Now, we turn our attention to the problem statement. $$\frac{XY}{YC} = \frac{AX}{XB}$$
But, $$ \frac{AX}{XB} =  \frac{AZ}{ZC} $$
Thus, if the problem statement were true, it would imply:
$$ \frac{AX}{XB} =  \frac{AZ}{ZC} = \frac{XY}{YC}$$
Thus,
$$\frac{CZ}{AZ} = \frac{YC}{XY}$$
Now, essentially what we can infer is that, $$YZ \parallel AB$$ an obvious fallacy. Hence I feel the question is wrong. Is this reasoning correct

Yes! You are correct that the stated statement is indeed wrong (and MyMolecules has in fact showed the correct version with a proof). For such problems involving ratios, I like to use a neat little trick to find/check solutions/statements.
We know that $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$. So imagine placing a mass of $1$ unit at $B$ and $C$ each, so that the center-of-mass (com) of $BC$ is at $D$. Now, for the side $AB$, we want the com to be at $X$. Clearly, placing a mass of $BX/AX$ units at $A$ does the job. The equivalent mass at $X$ is then $1+BX/AX$.
Now by something I like to call the uniqueness of com, $Y$ is the com of $XC$ (and also $AD$ and also the whole triangle). Thus $$\frac{XY}{YC}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{BX}{AX}}=\frac{AX}{AX+BX}=\frac{AX}{\color{red}{AB}}$$ which is the correct result!

How did you get the  'equivalent mass' at X. Why is it defined as the sum of masses at A and B

Also, how did you get that Y is the centre of mass of those segments.

For the equivalent mass thing, the thing to note is that we don't want to lose mass. Why this works does require a little proof, but it's not hard using a little analytical geometry. As for why $Y$ is the com, here's a result : If you join the vertices of a triangle to it's opposite sides at their coms, then the line segments intersect at the com of the triangle (and it is unique!).

Indeed as OP has analysed, the current problem statement $XY/YC = AX/XB$ is wrong. The correct result is $$ \frac{XY}{YC} = \frac{AX}{\color{red}{AB}} $$
This can be seen using van Aubel theorem,
$$ \frac{CY}{YX} = \frac{CZ}{ZA} + \frac{CD}{DB} $$
$$ = \frac{BX}{AX} + 1 = \frac{AB}{AX} $$
Taking reciprocal we get the intended result.
